# How to customize the code-block language of Sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, pygments

Consider the below situation:

```
.. code-block:: my_lang

    ...
```

If I want to make my_lang as some stuff such as Python, how can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you need to create a script (`_ext/mylanglexer.py`), and then add on the `extensions` on the conf.py

(***_ext** is a convention but not a must.*)

_ext/mylanglexer.py

```py
# _ext/mylanglexer.py

from pygments.lexers import get_lexer_by_name  # refer LEXERS
from pygments.lexers._mapping import LEXERS
from pygments.lexers.python import PythonLexer


def setup(app):
    # choose one, both ok
    app.add_lexer('my_lang', get_lexer_by_name('py'))
    # app.add_lexer('my_lang', PythonLexer)
```

conf.py

```
# conf.py

extensions = [
    ...
    '_ext.mylanglexer',  # types.ModuleType, they are likely the_module = __import__('sphinx.ext.autodoc')
]
```

at some [tutorial](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/development/tutorials/helloworld.html#using-the-extension) the tell you better add `sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("./_ext"))`
then `extensions = ['mylanglexer']`

Anyway, as long as you know that is a module, all extensions should be able to be `import ...`, so if your module is not in the default path, of course, you must append.

Now, it's working!

---

## How does it work

see the [pygements.lexers.**init**.py](https://github.com/pygments/pygments/blob/f6d3ce6/pygments/lexers/__init__.py#L104-L122)

```
# pygements.lexers.__init__.py

def get_lexer_by_name(_alias, **options):
    ...

    # lookup builtin lexers
    for module_name, name, aliases, _, _ in LEXERS.values():  # <-- Be focus on this line.
        if _alias.lower() in aliases:
            return _lexer_cache[name](**options)  # The class object (module_name+key_name), for example: pygments.lexers.python.PythonLexer(**options)
    # continue with lexers from setuptools entrypoints
    for cls in find_plugin_lexers():

        ...
        return cls(**options)

    raise ClassNotFound('no lexer for alias %r found' % _alias)
```

In which [LEXERS](https://github.com/pygments/pygments/blob/96eaeba/pygments/lexers/_mapping.py#L15-L545) is some kind of the following stuff.

```
# pygments.lexers._mapping.py

LEXERS = {
    # key_name: module_name, name, aliases: Tuple[str], _, _
    ...
    'ObjectiveCLexer': ('pygments.lexers.objective', 'Objective-C', ('objective-c', 'objectivec', 'obj-c', 'objc'), ('*.m', '*.h'), ('text/x-objective-c',)),
    'ObjectiveCppLexer': ('pygments.lexers.objective', 'Objective-C++', ('objective-c++', 'objectivec++', 'obj-c++', 'objc++'), ('*.mm', '*.hh'), ('text/x-objective-c++',)),
    'ObjectiveJLexer': ('pygments.lexers.javascript', 'Objective-J', ('objective-j', 'objectivej', 'obj-j', 'objj'), ('*.j',), ('text/x-objective-j',)),
    'OcamlLexer': ('pygments.lexers.ml', 'OCaml', ('ocaml',), ('*.ml', '*.mli', '*.mll', '*.mly'), ('text/x-ocaml',)),
    'OctaveLexer': ('pygments.lexers.matlab', 'Octave', ('octave',), ('*.m',), ('text/octave',)),
    'JsonLexer': ('pygments.lexers.data', 'JSON', ('json',), ('*.json', 'Pipfile.lock'), ('application/json',)),
    'PythonLexer': ('pygments.lexers.python', 'Python', ('python', 'py', 'sage', 'python3', 'py3'), ('*.py', '*.pyw', '*.jy', '*.sage', '*.sc', 'SConstruct', 'SConscript', '*.bzl', 'BUCK', 'BUILD', 'BUILD.bazel', 'WORKSPACE', '*.tac'), ('text/x-python', 'application/x-python', 'text/x-python3', 'application/x-python3')),
    ...
}
```

There you know, your `_alias` in the `aliases`, then will work!

How can I customize my style?

you can copy and do some modify the Lexer, such as `ObjectiveCLexer`, `JsonLexer` ...

finally `app.add_lexer('my_lang', YourLexer)`  that's kind of the problem.